# Correctly create a task for log-in function

Tags: c#, authentication, asynchronous, async-await, task

I was working on my windows form program, and i saw that the login function (linked to a simple button) freeze my application. I searched on internet and i found how to create a task, but i'm not sure about how it works ...

That's my login function, how can i correctly translate it into a task?

```
string sURL = url + "/login";
string result = null;

await Task.Run(() =>
{
    try
    {
        result = Web_api.MakeRequest("POST", sURL); //return null if there is some error
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("[frmLogin] --> result: " + result);
    }
});

if(result != null)
{
    try
    {
        Login_response accepted = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Login_response>(result);
        Debug.WriteLine("[frm_Login] --> accepted: " + accepted);

        if (accepted.login)
        {
            //throw new Exception();  
            Debug.WriteLine("[frm_login]: result " + result);
            frmMain frm = new frmMain();                             //calling the new form
            frm.Show();                                              //new form is show-up
            this.Hide();                                             //log-in form hide
            frm.FormClosed += Frm_FormClosed;                        //close the form
        }
    }
    //if server is down, or the id or password is wrong 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblLoginError.Visible = true;                            //pop-up the error label
        pbLogin.Visible = false;                                 //hide the progress-bar
        this.Style = MetroFramework.MetroColorStyle.Red;         //changing the color of the form
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex);
    }
}
else
{
    lblLoginError.Visible = true;                            //pop-up the error label
    pbLogin.Visible = false;                                 //hide the progress-bar
    this.Style = MetroFramework.MetroColorStyle.Red;         //changing the color of the form
}
```

EDIT: i provided a real (and working) soluction and i followed all the suggestion in the comments ... do you think this could be acceptable?

Comment: Any  UI blocking code like long running or depandand on external ressources like web request, you should wrap into a task and then ```await``` the result. a good condidate in your case would be the ```string result = Web_api.MakeRequest("POST", sURL);``` if it does have an ```Async``` function, to use that instead and await the result.

Comment: @Tomek thank you for the reply. I've checked the documentation, and i made an example, is that the "good way" for correctly declare and run a task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute any potentially long-running code on a background thread using a `Task`:

```
private async void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUser.Text.Trim()) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPassword.Text.Trim()))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You must insert a valid user/password format", "Login Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }

    //Progress bar start
    pbLogin.Visible = true; // BUT THIS PROGRESS BAR I STACK DUE TO STATIC DEFINITON OF LOGIN

    //Getting ID + Password
    User.username = txtUser.Text;
    User.password = txtPassword.Text;
    string sURL = Web_api.url + "/login";

    try
    {
        Login_response accepted = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //the following code gets executed on a background thread...
            string result = Web_api.MakeRequest("POST", sURL);
            Login_response accepted = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Login_response>(result);
            Debug.WriteLine("[frm_Login] --> accepted: " + accepted);
            return accepted;
        });
        
        //...and here you are back on the UI thread once the task has completed
        if (accepted.login)
        {
            //throw new Exception();  
            Debug.WriteLine("[frm_login]: result " + result);
            frmMain frm = new frmMain();                             //calling the new form
            frm.Show();                                              //new form is show-up
            this.Hide();                                             //log-in form hide
            frm.FormClosed += Frm_FormClosed;                        //close the form
        }
    }
    //if server is down, or the id or password is wrong 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblLoginError.Visible = true;                            //pop-up the error label
        pbLogin.Visible = false;                                 //hide the progress-bar
        this.Style = MetroFramework.MetroColorStyle.Red;         //changing the color of the form
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex);
    }
}
```

Event handlers always return `void`. They are an exception to the rule that says that an async method always should return a `Task` or a `Task<T>`.

Comment: so, just need to add it as async method ??

Comment: @zenek  yes and no, you need to change the vent handler to ```async void``` because you use ```async/await``` on a task inside of it.

Comment: i've take a look a little bit deeper, and i finally realized what was the difference, thank, now i have a workable example to study !

Comment: You should not run IO operations on a background task, it makes the code very difficult to debug. You should use the async pattern which is made for that specific purpose. Background tasks are for CPU bound operations.

Comment: Yes, but apparently `Web_api.MakeRequest` is synchronous in this case so then you don't really have a choice.

Answer (score -1):

You can create an async void method. It is actually the correct way to implement async callbacks for events such as button click.

First, let's make an asynchronous login method :

```
public async Task LoginAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var stream = await _http.GetStreamAsync($"{baseUrl}/login");
        var response = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<LoginResponse>(stream);
        if (!response.login)
        {
            throw new BusinessException<LoginError>(LoginError.LoginDenied);
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        throw new BusinessException<LoginError>(LoginError.LoginFailed, ex);
    }
}
```

Now we implement an asynchronous button callback:

```
private async void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await authentication.LoginAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        // handle login success here
    }
    catch (BusinessException<LoginError> ex) when (ex.Error == LoginError.LoginDenied)
    {
        // handle login denied here
    }
    catch (BusinessException<LoginError> ex) when (ex.Error == LoginError.LoginFailed)
    {
        // handle connection failed here
    }
}
```

If you want the `LoginAsync()` method to do some UI operations (for instance showing a form), you will need to use `ConfigureAwait(true)`. Otherwise, there is a risk that part of the method is executed on a different thread and UI operations will fail.

Comment: didn't really get how do that, can you please provide an example !?

Comment: @Zenek please see edit for simple implementation